# Laravel site rendering from local storage

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Through the zip archive, the user can upload the website to my disk. Then I unzip it and put it in private storage.

After all these actions, it has the following structure

[image]

The landing folder is the site itself that was uploaded by the user.

This is the method I use to render this site:

```
Route::get('/{site}', function ($site) {
  View::addLocation(storage_path('app/' . $site));
  return view('index', ['param1' => 'test param']);
});
```

We open it by URL and I have the following result

```
http://127.0.0.1/landing
```

The site renders perfectly, but the styles and scripts do not load

[image]

Here is what I have in index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="ua"><head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=480">
<title><?php echo $param1; ?></title>
<!-- Favicon -->
<link rel="icon" href="images/favicon_1aa7_19.png" type="image/png">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon_1aa7_19.png" type="image/png">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/reset50406_1dab_1.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/gothampro67c72_e5b0_2.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/slickdc1c6_5bc5_3.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/lightbox-minf2560_d182_4.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/timecirclese646d_fd7a_5.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style528fc_4d07_6.css" type="text/css">
<!--{{HEAD}}-->
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello from landing site</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you try using absolute path for example `/css/gothampro67c72_e5b0_2.css` to something like this `/landing/css/gothampro67c72_e5b0_2.css`

Comment: What do you mean by "local storage"? Why not use the correct links to the assets?

Comment: I would think it is the uploading user's responsibility to get their site to work based on what their site root will be etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the base url to be the root of your user's storage. You are using absolute paths (/css/...) so it will try to load your css files at yoursite.com/css/... instead of yoursite.com/landing/css/...

Adding the `<base>` tag to your user's site inside `<head>` will fix the issue:

```
<base href="https://yoursite.com/landing" target="_blank">
```

Or, instead of using the base tag, you could also just not use absolute paths, and use relative paths instead:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset50406_1dab_1.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/gothampro67c72_e5b0_2.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slickdc1c6_5bc5_3.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightbox-minf2560_d182_4.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/timecirclese646d_fd7a_5.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style528fc_4d07_6.css" type="text/css">
```

Notice how it's now `css/...` instead of `/css/...`